# Jquery replace table data instead of appending

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code which appends some rows to existing data in table with tbody id `manifest_table`.

```
$.each(order_data, function(i, item) {
    $('<tr>').html("<td>" + order_data[i][0] + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][1]  + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][2]  + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][3]  + "</td>").appendTo('#manifest_table');
});

<table id="manifest_table" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-sort-name="dispatch_by_date" data-page-list="[50, 100]" data-page-size="50" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Order Item ID</th>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Channel</th>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Courier</th>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Tracking</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="manifest_table">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to know to replace the whole table body instead of appending it?

Comment: use `.html()` method on tbody then.

Comment: Might be best to keep your loop, and just clear the `tbody` prior to the loop appends. Just add `$('#manifest_table').html('');` at the start, or IIRC you can just use `$('#manifest_table').empty();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are **looping**. So, before you start the loop, just empty:

```
$('#manifest_table').empty();   // or
$('#manifest_table').html('');  // use this, any one of the two
$.each(order_data, function(i, item) {
    $('<tr>').html("<td>" + order_data[i][0] + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][1]  + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][2]  + "</td><td>" + order_data[i][3]  + "</td>").appendTo('#manifest_table');
});
```